# Printstream Skipping Printing of First Line in a File

Tags: java, printstream

I have this code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String filePath = (args[0]);



            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            String strLine = br.readLine();
            //Read File Line By Line and Print the content on the console
             PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream( //printing output to user specified text file (command line argument: outputfile)
                    args[1]+".txt"));


            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            char [] words = strLine.toCharArray();
            System.out.println (strLine);
                Arrays.sort(words);
                out.println(words);
            }
            //close the streams
            br.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("An IOException was caught, Re-open program and enter correct number of arguments :"+e.getMessage());
            }

    }


}
```

It does what I want it to do but it is skipping the first line of an input file.

Say for example the input file contained this list of words:
bye
red
blue

it would output:
edr
belu

and skip printing:
bey

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
String strLine = br.readLine();
```

to

```
String strLine = null;
```

The first line is consumed on the current line (and later discarded) in your current version, when `while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)` executes.